# Angular2: Are dynamically created injectors (created via Injector.create(...)) ever destroyed?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, dynamically-generated, application-lifecycle, angular-injector

Need some comments on the lifecycle of injectors created with `Injector.create` method

I tried to create a component via `ViewContainerRef.createComponent(...)` and provide dynamically generated dependencies using a custom injector that was passed in arguments. That injector had a parent injector inherited from the host component.

When after some time I destroyed that component, I noticed that the services I had provided in the dynamic injector didn't execute the `ngOnDestroy` method.

Nevertheless, all the services provided via `@Component` decorator (in the parent component) were  successfully destroyed (in fact, they're always destroyed this way).

What can be the reason of such behaviour? Is there a way to destroy dynamically created injectors?

Here's an StackBlitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vstiqn

When I close the parent component via the toggle button, I expect that the `ChildService` would call `ngOnDestroy` method as the `ParentService` does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to destroy an `Injector` manually is to go with an `EnvironmentInjector` which has the `destroy` method.

With your example that would be :

```
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  myInjector?:EnvironmentInjector

  constructor(
    private readonly viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef,
    private readonly environmentInjector: EnvironmentInjector,
    private readonly parentService: ParentService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myInjector = createEnvironmentInjector( [ChildService],
      this.environmentInjector,
    ); // create

    this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(ChildComponent, {
      injector: this.myInjector,
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.myInjector?.destroy() // destroy
    console.log('ParentComponent destroyed'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, this worked for me perfectly - thanks a lot! 
However, now I'm wondering if something like this is possible in older versions of Angular:)
Btw what do you think - is it okay to provide dynamic dependencies this way?

Comment: Yeah, that's the way to go ! EnvironmentInjector works since standalone and v14.

Comment: I was thinking about your solution again - just one small notice about it 

If your custom environment injector inherits the environment injector from current scope - it's important to pass it via the corresponding `environmentInjector` property. In other case, you risk overriding some critical tokens from the `Element Injector` hierarchy.